# I wish to do conditionally formatting according to values of cells inside a html table that comes out of a GridView via ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I have got an issue. The code I have written is not functioning. Please correct where I am wrong.

Here is the overall problem. Code follows afterwards.

I wrote a ASP.NET script that retrieves data from multiple external Excel files and displays this code on an .aspx page. I wish to **format the content of these tables conditionally** according to some rules of meaning like "good/satisfactory/bad".

- Rules for each table are distinct.the value of the cell corresponding to "good" in Table1 is different than the value of the cell corresponding to "good"in Table2
- Tables can be identified in the HTML page rendered upon their ID like "GridView1" etc (Same ID of the GridViews controls from the sourcing ASP.NET page). I see that browser holds the IDs.

  ```
  .bad { background-color:red}
  .satisfactory {background-color:yellow}
  .good {background-color:green}
  ```

embedding jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("document").load(function () {
            $("#GridView1 td").each(
                function () {
                    var score = $(this).text();
                    if (score <= 2000) {
                        $(this).addClass("good") ;
                    }
                    else if (score > 2000 && score <=3999) {
                        $(this).addClass("satisfactory");
                    } else if (score>= 4000) {
                        $(this).addClass("bad");
                    }
                });
        })
    </script>
```

Sample of code from ASP.NET definition of GridView1 control that will render as HTML Table ID="GridView1". This is an excerpt from Page.aspx

```
<div >
    <span class="labelPPMIntern" style="background-color:#66CCFF;">Score</span>
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="410px" CellPadding="4"  GridLines="Both">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
        <RowStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#66CCFF" />
    </asp:GridView></div>
```

Where I am wrong?
 After rendering my current code, there is no change in Background-color (as it should have been according to the verification of the values and assignation of classes to the s. )

Comment: I'm suspecting that the RowStyle of your grid view is putting the styles inline on the html. The in line style will take precedent over your class. Try removing the background color in the row style and see what happens.

Comment: I removed the inline formatting of the Rows in the .aspx code, still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was caused by a mix of causes:

- $("document").**ready**(function ()...

> thank you Joseph Norris. There was a matter of an *incorrect event handler*.
>   I was using  $("document").*load*(function ()

- $(**'#GridView1 tr>td'**).each( ..

> There was a matter of putting the *right jQuery selectors*. I sorted it out by filtering the selectors from general to particular.

this is the working piece of code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $('#GridView1 tr>td').each(

            function () {
                var score = parseFloat($(this).text());
                if (score <= 2000 && score>0) {
                    $(this).addClass("good");

                }
                else if (score > 2000 && score <=3999) {
                    $(this).addClass("satisfactory");
                } else if (score>= 4000 ) {
                    $(this).addClass("bad");
                }
            });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

.net renames the ID values of webform objects, so you need the ClientIDMode="Static" attribute to your gridview declaration, otherwise your ID is something like 
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1.

On my code, I do such manipulations in codebehind on a ItemDataBound event.

Comment: I switched the ClientIDMode="Static", but still I do not get the output I wish. As a matter it seems there is no jQuery is not functioning at all.(no background color change). There must be something else too.

Comment: Thank you, Antoine. I tried something with the RowDataBound event  , but I have had an issue that only the first row of the first table was displayed after entering the function fired by this event in the aspx.cs page. Could you point me towards a working solution that involves the ItemDataBound event instead? thanks

Comment: I happen to have a .net project and I tested this with it. 

<asp:GridView ID="gridEMailTemplates" ClientIDMode="Static"

      $('#gridEMailTemplates td').each(
                 function ()
                 {
                     $(this).css("color","red")
                 }
                );

All the non hyperlinks changed to red.

Comment: is it possible that var score = $(this).text();  is not legit for values, but only for text?  my conditional formatting condition refers to value comparison

Comment: Try the $(this).css("color","red") test for now. If it works then you know you're accessing the cells that your conditional might be the problem.

Comment: Not working. tried $("document").load(function () {
            $('#GridView1 td').each(

                function () {
                    $(this).css("color","red")
                });
        }) . It seems there is something more than the conditional. I am on Chrome. I am checking on Firefox.I figure out there is support for the library.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {})
or
function pageLoad(sender, args) {}

works for me, but not $("document").load(function () {})

Comment: There must be something with the Selector. jQuery works for an ID of a label from ASP which got into a <span> in HTML. I am checking at the moment  $('#GridView1').each(

                function () {
                    $(this).css("color", "red")

Comment: It does not work for  $('#GridView1').each(

                function () {
                    $(this).css("color", "red")